# Use String/int/long etc. in one class

Tags: java, string, class, int, void

I want to use:

```
user_update("lastlogin", INT);
user_update("nick", STRING);
user_update("money" DOUBLE);
```

but in one class:

```
public void update_user(String what, String value){
[...]
}
```

So here is my question : How can I handle INT, STRING, DOUBLE in class?

```
public void update_user(String what, String/int/double value){
[...]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may as well use a generic method

```
public <T> void update_user(String what, T value) {}
```

This may be useful if you are intended to add more types used by the method in the future. Using generics may save you from writing too much boilerplate code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object`.

```
public void update_user(String what, Object value){}
```

Take a look here

[java.lang.Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

---

**OR**

you can implement 3 methods:

```
public void update_user(String what, String value){}

public void update_user(String what, int value){}

public void update_user(String what, double value){}
```